# Remove values from a javascript table

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I currently just have a simple table full of users who have entered the command: `~afk`
Example:

```js
var afkMembers = []
client.on('message' async message => {
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '~afk') {
afkMembers.push(message.author.id)
return message.channel.send('you are now marked as AFK')
}

if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '~back') {
//remove the element from the table
return message.channel.send('you are now marked as back')
}

});
```

I'm just wondering how I would remove the users value from the table. 
It is probably quite simple, however I cannot find a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a certain element from in array with [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const index = afkMembers.indexOf(message.author.id);
if (index === -1) return message.channel.send('Your are not marked as AFK');
afkMembers.splice(index, 1);
```

However, I would actually suggest rewriting both commands and using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an `Array`. `Sets` are unique because a value in a set may only appear once; there are no duplicates. It also has unique methods that would be helpful such as [`Set.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add), [`Set.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete), and [`Set.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

```js
const afkMembers = new Set();

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "~afk") {
    if (afkMembers.has(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send("You are already marked as AFK!");

    afkMembers.add(message.author.id);
    message.channel.send("you are now marked as AFK");

  } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "~back") {
    if (!afkMembers.has(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send("You are not marked as AFK!");

    afkMembers.delete(message.author.id);
    message.channel.send("You are now marked as back");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the value like this :

```
afkMembers.splice(afkMembers.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're simply manipulating an array,
If I'm not missing something in the explanation, I would use splice to remove the user.

```
afkMembers.splice(afkMembers.indexOf(message.author.id), 1);
```